# types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part "dataitem column"

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'am getting the error when executing my sql query "types don't match between the anchor and the recursive".
My query :

```
;WITH FA_CTE  AS
(
SELECT
    fa.name as Data1,
    fa.lnumber as Data2,
    fa.allnumber as Data3,
    fa.productname as Data4

  FROM
   (
     SELECT      A.name, A.lnumber, A.allnumber, A.productname
FROM            soldproduct AS A INNER JOIN Account AS B ON A.account = B.accountid
) fa

)
 , tmp1(Data1, Data2, Data3, DataItem , Data4) as (
select Data1, Data2, Data3, LEFT(Data4, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-')-1),
STUFF(Data4, 1, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-'), '')
from FA_CTE
union all
select Data1, Data2, Data3, LEFT(Data4, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-')-1),
STUFF(Data4, 1, CHARINDEX('-',Data4+'-'), '')
from tmp1
```

)

```
select Data1, Data2, Data3, DataItem AS Data4
from tmp1
order by Data1
```

Comment: Not seeing why the type conversion is a problem, but that looks like infinite recursion. Maybe the better question is what are you trying to do because I don't think a recursive CTE is the tool you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ask me why SQL Server has trouble with string lengths when working with recursive CTEs, but I have solved this problem in the past by explicitly casting the computed string columns:

```
tmp1(Data1, Data2, Data3, DataItem, Data4) as (
 select Data1, Data2, Data3,
        convert(varchar(max), LEFT(Data4, CHARINDEX('-', Data4 + '-') - 1)),
        convert(varchar(max), STUFF(Data4, 1, CHARINDEX('-', Data4 + '-'), ''))
 from FA_CTE
 union all
 select Data1, Data2, Data3,
        convert(varchar(max), LEFT(Data4, CHARINDEX('-', Data4 + '-') - 1)),
        convert(varchar(max), STUFF(Data4, 1, CHARINDEX('-', Data4 + '-'), ''))
 from tmp1
```